# Why do I get the Exception SqlException IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, csv

```
HeuteDb heute = new HeuteDb();
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\ASPlearning\DATA\Data.csv";

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        List<string> items = line.Split(';').ToList();

        heute.Uhrzeit = items[0];
        heute.Energie = items[1];

        _context.HeutesDb.Add(heute);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I have a CSV file which I want to store into my database. There is an  `ID` which is set as a primary key and the `Uhrzeit` and the `Energie` values.

After every line of the CSV file, I save the changes to the database. It only saves the first line in the database, then it throws an error.

What is the best way to save a CSV file into a database?

Comment: The table `HeutesDb` in your database has a field marked as primary key, so you should set it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your loop

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    List<string> items = line.Split(';').ToList();

    heute.Uhrzeit = items[0];
    heute.Energie = items[1];

    _context.HeutesDb.Add(heute);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You add again and again the same instance *heute* to your database. But the instance is the same, so after the first successful insert, EF will automatically set the property ID, supposed to contain the IDENTITY value to the value obtained performing the first insert.
At the next loop, the same instance (with the ID property still set from the previous loop) is passed again for adding, but, at this time, the engine rejects the insert because you are not supposed to set a value for ID unless you call *SET IDENTITY_INSERT 'tablename' ON* for your table.

You fix it simply moving the initialization for the *heute* variable inside the loop.

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    
    List<string> items = line.Split(';').ToList();

    HeuteDb heute = new HeuteDb();
    heute.Uhrzeit = items[0];
    heute.Energie = items[1];

    _context.HeutesDb.Add(heute);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now, at each loop, the *heute* instance and its ID property are new without any leftover from the previous loop and the db engine will insert your records.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to either set autoincrement of your Identity column in the database (value is increased by 1 automatically) - or you need to specify a value on your identity Column while inserting,

the first entry is saved successfully because the int datatype has an default value of 0, since 0 does not exist as an entry it will allow to be saved (next record needs different id)